# Formatting some data about some airlines

Tags: php, formatting

```
function reformat($data, $registration = false) {
    // Initializing aircompanies codes
    $iata = new iata;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i = $i + 6) {
        if ($registration) {
            $r = str_replace('<nobr>', '', $this->prep_value($data[$i]));
            $block[$i]['reis'] = str_replace('</nobr>', '', $r);
            $a = explode(' ', $block[$i]['reis']);
            $block[$i]['company'] = $a[0];
        } else {
            $r = explode('&nbsp;', $this->prep_value($data[$i]));
            $block[$i]['reis'] = (strlen($r[0]) > 2) ? strrev(substr(strrev($r[0]), 15, 2)) . ' ' . $r[1] : $r[0] . ' ' . $r[1];
            $block[$i]['company'] = (strlen($r[0]) > 2) ? strrev(substr(strrev($r[0]), 15, 2)) : $r[0];
        }
        $block[$i]['companyname'] = $iata->aircompanies[strtoupper($block[$i]['company'])];
        if (file_exists(ROOT_HTML_PATH . '/content/aircompanies/' . $block[$i]['company'] . '.png')) {
            $block[$i]['company'] = $block[$i]['company'] . '.png';
        } else {
            /**
             * @todo Write e-mail notifications, but only once;
             */
        }
        $block[$i]['airport'] = $this->prep_value($data[$i + 1]);
        $block[$i]['terminal'] = substr(strrev($this->prep_value($data[$i + 2])), 2, 1);
        $block[$i]['shedtime'] = $this->prep_value($data[$i + 3]);
        $block[$i]['facttime'] = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $this->prep_value($data[$i + 4]));
        $block[$i]['status'] = str_replace('&nbsp', '<br />', trim(strip_tags($this->prep_value($data[$i + 5]), '<img />'), '&nbsp;/r/n'));
        $block[$i]['status'] = str_replace(';', '', $block[$i]['status']);
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Comment: This question could use some explanation of what the code is supposed to do and how it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function reformat($data, $registration = false) {
    // Initializing aircompanies codes
    $iata = new iata;
    $block = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i += 6) {
        $block[$i] = array(
            'airport'  => $this->prep_value($data[$i + 1]),
            'terminal' => substr(strrev($this->prep_value($data[$i + 2])), 2, 1),
            'shedtime' => $this->prep_value($data[$i + 3]),
            'facttime' => str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $this->prep_value($data[$i + 4])),
            'status'   => str_replace(';', '', 
                              str_replace('&nbsp', '<br />', 
                                  trim(
                                      strip_tags($this->prep_value($data[$i + 5]), '<img />'), 
                                      '&nbsp;/r/n'
                                  )
                              )
                          ),
        );

        if ($registration) {
            $r = str_replace('<nobr>', '', $this->prep_value($data[$i]));
            $block[$i]['reis'] = str_replace('</nobr>', '', $r);
            $a = explode(' ', trim($block[$i]['reis']));
            $block[$i]['company'] = $a[0];
        } else {
            $r = explode('&nbsp;', $this->prep_value($data[$i]));
            $block[$i]['company'] = (strlen($r[0]) > 2) ? substr($r[0], -17, 2) : $r[0];
            $block[$i]['reis'] = $block[$i]['company'] . ' ' . $r[1];
        }
        $block[$i]['companyname'] = $iata->aircompanies[strtoupper($block[$i]['company'])];
        if (file_exists(ROOT_HTML_PATH . '/content/aircompanies/' . $block[$i]['company'] . '.png')) {
            $block[$i]['company'] = $block[$i]['company'] . '.png';
        } else {
            /**
             * @todo Write e-mail notifications, but only once;
             */
        }
    }
    return $block;
}
```

But it is many questions here:

```
$this->prep_value($data[$i + 2])
```

It is really bad idea. May be you need a little another cycle, like

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data) - 6; $i ++) { // or something for preventing array index overloading
```

It would be much better.
But I cannot know it for sure.

Comment: `$this->prep_value($data[$i + 2])`
That's cause of parsing data. Sorry, could do nothing with this. Maybe =)
`for ($i = 0; $i < count($data) - 6; $i ++) `
That's cause i use for block[0] - first six items, for block[1] - next six items.
Really, don't know what to do with this.

Comment: It appears that your data comes in as an array `$data`. What you could consider based on what is in that data array, is to perform all `str_replace` operations in one go at the top (if feasible). You could flatten the array initially with `json_encode` then do `str_replace` on all the `<br/>`, `/r/n`, `$nbsp` etc. and then recreate it with `json_decode`. That could speed the process up. Again it depends on your data.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.